# How download file with SwiftyDropbox? Error with path

Tags: ios, swift, swiftydropbox

I'm trying to download a file with SwiftyDropbox but I have problemas with the path. I have a file in mi Dropbox "prueba.txt":

[Dropbox file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM7N1.png)

And this is the code that I use to download in my app.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyDropbox

let clientDB = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient

class Controller: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    DropboxClientsManager.authorizeFromController(UIApplication.shared, controller: self, openURL: {
        (url: URL) -> Void in UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    })

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let directoryURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let destURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("/test.txt")
    let destination: (URL, HTTPURLResponse) -> URL = { temporaryURL, response in
        return destURL
    }

    clientDB?.files.download(path: "/prueba.txt", overwrite: true, destination: destination)
        .response{ response, error in
            if response != nil{
                self.cargarDatosCliente()
                //print (response)
            } else if let error = error{
                print (error)
            }
        }

        .progress{ progressData in
            print(progressData)
        }
    }
}
```

I try different ways but always obtain the same problem with "path", always the error is `path/not_found/...`
I try with other path but is the same problem.
Could you help me? Where is my mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "/prueba.txt" is a local file path. Dropbox expects you to give it a file path for their remote server.

You can retrieve those by using [listFolder](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/FilesRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox11FilesRoutes10listFolderFT4pathSS9recursiveSb16includeMediaInfoSb14includeDeletedSb31includeHasExplicitSharedMembersSb21includeMountedFoldersSb5limitGSqVs6UInt32_10sharedLinkGSqCCS_5Files10SharedLink_21includePropertyGroupsGSqOCS_14FileProperties18TemplateFilterBase__GCS_10RpcRequestCS2_26ListFolderResultSerializerCS2_25ListFolderErrorSerializer_) and [listFolderContinue](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/FilesRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox11FilesRoutes18listFolderContinueFT6cursorSS_GCS_10RpcRequestCCS_5Files26ListFolderResultSerializerCS2_33ListFolderContinueErrorSerializer_).

For example, if you want to retrieve the file paths in the root folder of your app or dropbox use:

```
var path = ""
clientDB?.files.listFolder(path: path).response(completionHandler: { response, error in
            if let response = response {
                let fileMetadata = response.entries
                if response.hasMore {
                    // Store results found so far
                    // If there are more entries, you can use `listFolderContinue` to retrieve the rest.
                } else {
                    // You have all information. You can use it to download files.
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                // Handle errors
            }
        })
```

The fileMetadata contains the path you need. For example, you can get the path to the first file like this:

```
let path = fileMetadata[0].pathDisplay
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting metadata about files from the API, this would be the "pathLower" property of a FileMetadata object.

```
client?.files.download(path: fileMetadata.pathLower!, overwrite: true, destination: destination)
                            .response { response, error in
                                if let response = response {
                                    print(response)
                                } else if let error = error {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                            }
```