# Dropbox Files.download does not start when number of files in folder is > 1000

Tags: arrays, swift, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

I am cross-posting this from my initial question in DropBox forums. I think it would be good to have this here as well for swiftydropbox users.

I'm having trouble downloading entire folders to a local device via swiftyDropbox.
I am doing the ListFolder and ListFolderContinue (which I observe that it chunks it to ~500 files per response) and appending it to a local array.

After which, I pass this array to files.download. However, I am finding out that in cases where my folder is >1000 files (txt files ~0.5-1kb in size), the download process will not start.

```
static func downloadMissingFiles(client: DropboxClient, callingProcess: String) {
      let fileManager = FileManager.default
      let localBaseURL = fileManager.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("Cloud/Dropbox", isDirectory: true)
      
      // Data will be in the form of
      // key   : "/workouts/workout list 1/peye.mrc"
      // value : "//workouts/workout list 1/peye.mrc=_-_=015ca880b135d01000000020cb26de0"
      for dbFiles in Array(dbFileNameRevDict) {
        let dbFilePathLower = dbFiles.key
        let dbFileNameRev = dbFiles.value
        let fullURL = localBaseURL.appendingPathComponent(dbFileNameRev)
        
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fullURL.path) {
          print("  -> FILE EXISTS dbFileNameRev:\(dbFileNameRev)")
          localFileList.append(dbFileNameRev)
        } else {
          let destination : (URL, HTTPURLResponse) -> URL = { temporaryURL, response in
            return fullURL
          }
          
          client.files.download(path:dbFilePathLower, overwrite: true, destination: destination)
            .response { response, error in
              if let (_, url) = response {
                print("====> DOWNLOADED:\(url.lastPathComponent)")
              } else if let error = error {
               print(error)
            }
            /// This gives a progress of every single file on it's own. Hence, useless
            // .progress { progressData in
            //  print(progressData)
            // }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have tried various method to download these files, I also tried to do a serial queue to iterate the array of files one by one but it doesn't work.

This is how I process the ListFolder and ListFolderContinue, looking at the hasMore attribute.

```
      // https://stackoverflow.com/a/52870045/14414215
      if result.hasMore == true {
        processDBMore(client: client, cursor: result.cursor)
      } else {
        // When there is no more files (as indicated by hasMore == false)
        // start downloading the files
        downloadMissingFiles(client: client, callingProcess: "processDBMore-Finish")
        print("PrcessDBMore - dropboxGroup.leave")
        dropboxGroup.leave()
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Greg (swiftyDropbox)

> Each 'client.files.download' call downloads one file by making one
> HTTPS request to the Dropbox API servers. Additionally, these calls
> run asynchronously, and will not block until the call completes. That
> is, calling 'client.files.download' will start the HTTPS request, but
> will itself return before it's complete and the response is fully
> received. (It just runs the supplied block once the request is done.)
> That being the case, in the code you showed here, you're actually
> starting 1000 connections in a row, at almost the same time, so it's
> likely exhausting your network connection. You should update your code
> to only submit one (or a few) of these at a time. You mentioned you
> tried a serial queue, but that may be running in to the same issue,
> since the actual requests run asynchronously.

So I was searching for other solutions when I came across this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/66227963/14414215 which greatly helped in my understanding of how semaphore works and how implementing semaphores (besides using dispatchGroups) is able to properly control the files.download calls.

```
   static func downloadMissingFiles(client: DropboxClient, callingProcess: String) {
      let fileManager = FileManager.default
      let localBaseURL = fileManager.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("Cloud/Dropbox", isDirectory: true)
      let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)  // insert desired concurrent downloads value here.

      // Data will be in the form of
      // key   : "/workouts/workout list 1/peye.mrc"
      // value : "//workouts/workout list 1/peye.mrc=_-_=015ca880b135d01000000020cb26de0"
      DispatchQueue.global().async { // Wrap the call within an async block
      for dbFiles in Array(dbFileNameRevDict) {
        semaphore.wait() // Decrement the semaphore counter
        let dbFilePathLower = dbFiles.key
        let dbFileNameRev = dbFiles.value
        let fullURL = localBaseURL.appendingPathComponent(dbFileNameRev)
        
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fullURL.path) {
          print("  -> FILE EXISTS dbFileNameRev:\(dbFileNameRev)")
          localFileList.append(dbFileNameRev)
          semaphore.signal()  // Increment semaphore counter
        } else {
          let destination : (URL, HTTPURLResponse) -> URL = { temporaryURL, response in
            return fullURL
          }
          
          client.files.download(path:dbFilePathLower, overwrite: true, destination: destination)
            .response { response, error in
              if let (_, url) = response {
                print("====> DOWNLOADED:\(url.lastPathComponent)")
                // we've reached here means we've successfully download the file
                // So we can (release)increment semaphore counter
                semaphore.signal() 
              } else if let error = error {
               print(error)
            }
            /// This gives a progress of every single file on it's own. Hence, useless
            // .progress { progressData in
            //  print(progressData)
            // }
        }
      }
    }
   }
  }
```